# Is there a way to loop over all of the toys in my code to accomodate more toys?

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, innerhtml

I just completed a beginner JavaScript tutorial and I wanted to create a simple program that prints out how many toys a customer would like to buy using a drop-down menu to select the quantity. I have included both HTML and JavaScript code in my post as below.

Here is the HTML code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Toy Purchase </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pokemon Related Toys</h1>
<div>
    <h2>Pokemon plush toys</h2>
    <label for="Bulbasaurquantity">Bulbasaur Plush Quantity (from 0-5):</label>
    <input type="number" id="Bulbasaurquantity" class="plushquantity" min="0" max="5"><br>
    <label for="Plush quantity">Squirtle Plush Quantity (from 0-5):</label>
    <input type="number" id="Squirtlequantity" class="plushquantity" min="0" max="5"><br>
    <label for="Plush quantity">Charmander Plush Quantity (from 0-5):</label>
    <input type="number" id="Charmanderquantity" class="plushquantity" min="0" max="5"><br>

    <label id="PokemonPlushQuantity">Pokemon Plushes Bought:</label>
    <button type="button" id="PlushAll">CompletedPokemonPlushes</button>
</div>
<script src="EcommerceProject.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript code that I've written so far:

```
var plushQuantity = 0;

document.getElementById("PlushAll").onclick = function(){
    var Bulbasaurvalue = document.getElementById("Bulbasaurquantity").value;
    Bulbavalue = Number(Bulbasaurvalue); 
    var Squirtlevalue = document.getElementById("Squirtlequantity").value;
    Squirvalue = Number(Squirtlevalue);  
    var Charmandervalue = document.getElementById("Charmanderquantity").value;
    Charvalue = Number(Charmandervalue); 
    PlushNumber = plushQuantity + Bulbavalue + Squirvalue + Charvalue; 
    console.log(`You are buying ${PlushNumber} Pokemon plushes.`); 
    updatePlushcount(); 
} 
function updatePlushcount(){
   document.getElementById("PokemonPlushQuantity").innerHTML =`You are purchasing ${PlushNumber} Pokemon plushes.`;
}
```

The code runs properly and displays the output in the console but the function would need to be updated every time I added a new plush or another toy category. I've also tried to add checkboxes or radio buttons to filter down to only the toys that a person wants to buy and adding them up using a function but I haven't been successful so far. I would appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions for improving my sample website.

Comment: Don't use separate variables for each category. Use an array of objects like `{category: "Bulbasaur", count: 0}`. Or a single dictionary whose keys are the toy categories, e.g. `{Bulbasaur: 0, Squirtle: 5, ...}`